# google's notebook on vertex ai throwing following error: type name google.VertexModel is different from expected: Model

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I got this error, when compiling my pipeline:

> type name google.VertexModel is different from expected: Model

when running the following notebook by google: [automl_tabular_classification_beans](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/master/notebooks/official/pipelines/automl_tabular_classification_beans.ipynb)

I suppose that kubeflow v2 is not able to handle (yet) google.vertexmodel as type for component input. However, I've been browsing a bit and did not find any good clue, or refs (kfp documentation for v2 is not up to date..) to solve this issue. Hopefully someone here can give me a good pointer? I look forward to all of your ideas.

Cheers

Comment: Using Kubeflow Pipelines version 1.8.9, Vertex AI SDK 1.7.0, and version 0.2.0 of the components library should fix this issue. See this codelab for more info: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro#3

Answer (score 0):

Google.Vertex is defined here:

https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/286a49547cce763c502592c822296aa60f50b3e8/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/types/artifact_types.py#L20

Here is an example on how to define it:

https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/286a49547cce763c502592c822296aa60f50b3e8/components/google-cloud/tests/types/artifact_types_test.py#L22

For example,

```
from google_cloud_pipeline_components.types import artifact_types
model = artifact_types.VertexModel(uri='YOUR_MODEL_URI_STRING')
```

Can you try specifying your model using the syntax above and let us know if this works for your code?

Answer (score 0):

This was a breaking change with release 0.1.9. Here there are some recommendation:

1. Pin your release to 0.1.7 and continue to use the Model type.
2. Use 0.1.9 and switch the output from Output[Model] to Output[Artifact].
3. Try 0.2.0 release, documentation [here](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.2.0/google_cloud_pipeline_components.aiplatform.html).

Hope these suggestions work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).